# adding custom content to header in fullcalendar timeline view

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to add additional content to the header for each day in timeline view

According to this link:

> https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/311

it should be doable by hooking into resourceRender.

But as far as I can tell, and what I have tried so far, I can only get hold of the resource it self and not the header per day.

I have created a codepen and hooked into resourceRender to play around with: https://codepen.io/thomasabcd/pen/YzzezoO

```
resourceRender: function(renderInfo){
  console.log(renderInfo.el);
},
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "I can only get hold of the resource it self and not the header per day." ...yes that's true. The headers are not related to individual resources. In timeline view the headers are technically the timeslots, not column headers. You have limited control over what can appear in a slot label, via https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat . You could also get direct access using selectors, if you know which times will be visible - each header's HTML looks something like `<th class="fc-widget-header" data-date="2019-11-03T09:00:00">`

Comment: (The reason it's different from that codepen in the github issue link is because that's using timegrid view, not timeline, and so the header of the resource is at the top. In timeline view the resource header is at the side.)

Comment: thanks. I made it work by looking at how to access each header's HTML as you suggested and posted a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody else faces the same issue, I found a solution by hooking into the datesRender-callback. The code below makes a check and only adds the additional HTML to resourceTimelineWeek. Just remove the check if you don't need it.

See Codepen here: https://codepen.io/thomasabcd/pen/jOOZYRm

```
datesRender: function(renderInfo) {
      let viewType = renderInfo.view.viewSpec.type;
      if (viewType == "resourceTimelineWeek") {
        let dateHeaders = renderInfo.el.querySelectorAll("th[data-date]");
        dateHeaders.forEach(element => {
          let headerDate = element.dataset.date;
          let headerText = element.querySelector(".fc-cell-text");
          let extraHTML = "<p>some text</p>";
          headerText.innerHTML = headerText.innerHTML + extraHTML;
        })
      }
    }
```